# What's the difference between window.onload() and dojo.domReady

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have met an issue on dojo v1.8.3 :when I use the CODE_A:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function( dom) {
   textRegion2CountryInfo = com_ibm_bpm_global.coachView.byControlId(["textRegion2CountryInfo" + ""]).context.binding.get("value");
   console.log("regionString:" + textRegion2CountryInfo);
});
```

instead of CODE_B:

```
window.onload=function(){
   textRegion2CountryInfo = com_ibm_bpm_global.coachView.byControlId(["textRegion2CountryInfo" + ""]).context.binding.get("value");
   console.log("regionString:" + textRegion2CountryInfo);
}
```

There are 2 different results:CODE_A will display an error message "ReferenceError: com_ibm_bpm_global is not defined" in firebug,but the CODE_B will display the correct value.

I think there may be  difference between window.onload and dojo/domReady,I googled for solution,but I still have no idea,any help will be appreciatied.
BTW:com_ibm_bpm_global.coachView.byControlId(["textRegion2CountryInfo" + ""]).context.binding.get("value") is an IBPM API,I use it to cach server data in an element of page.

**reference**

[Dojo and the onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252753/dojo-and-the-onload-event)

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/addOnLoad.html

Comment: How do you load com_ibm_bpm_global?

Comment: onload would wait for script to finish coming in, if they were started already at that later point than ready. this includes amd modules, but you might just be buying enough time with the later event for something to load...

Comment: com_ibm_bpm_global.coachView.byControlId(["textRegion2CountryInfo" + ""]).context.binding.get("value") is an IBPM API,I use it to cach the server data in an element of page. the wiki:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.0/com.ibm.wbpm.wle.editor.doc/develop/topics/rglobalobject.html?cp=SSFPJS_8.5.0&lang=en